# font-face not working in django

Tags: css, django

In django (local test project) I have my `style.css` file in a static folder which is works perfect and style applies to template. static folder contain an image folder and a fonts folder. The content of image folder appear in browser but the fonts not!!!
here is my `font-face` code:

```
font-family: '‌‌‌BMitra';
src: url('fonts/BMitra.eot?#') format('eot'),
url('fonts/BMitra.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/BMitra.woff') format('woff');
```

I check css by firebug and find my personal font is disable and browser uses tahoma instead:

```
direction: rtl;
color: #092E20;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: BMitra, Tahoma, Arial;
text-align: right;
```

how do you use font-face in django?

Comment: has this since been resolved? im having the same problem

Answer (score 7):

As you have mentioned you directory structure is:

- static

  - css

    - my_css_file.css
  - fonts

    - font1
    - font2

Then in your `my_css_file.css` file you need to step up one folder to access fonts:

```
url('../fonts/BMitra.ttf')
```

Comment: no I have a static folder has an image folder and and and fonts folder plus a style.css file which is directly in static folder. url('fonts/BMitra.ttf') is correct. the same css works out of django but in django I just can not have fonts

Answer (score 4):

So just in case anyone is still running into this problem, I couldn't find an answer anywhere else. Inside the CSS it won't work using relative paths, only through the absolute path starting from the static folder, like so:

```
src: url('/static/fonts/BMitra.eot?#') format('eot'),
```

Comment: I have the same issue however this did not work for me in Django 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to CORS issue. Are your fonts working with Chrome ?

This might help:

http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/18/configure-amazon-s3-for-cross-origin-resourse-sharing-to-host-a-web-font/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to path edition, you should change:

```
src: url('fonts/BMitra.eot?#') format('eot'),
```

to:

```
src: url('fonts/BMitra.eot?#') format('eot');
```